# Help Please: Suppose $df$ is constant. Then, $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is an affine function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

How should I approach this? I was thinking of examining the partial derivatives $df_i/dx_j = c_{ij}$, but I'm not sure how helpful that is / whether I could "recover" a function from its partial derivatives, possibly by integration? I was also thinking of using the MVT, but got stuck. Any help? Been stuck for an hour on this problem

Update:

Let's consider a point $x_0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $df$ is constant, the derivative $df(x)$ is the same for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Denote this constant derivative by $A$, which is an $m \times n$ matrix.

Now, let's define a new function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ as follows: $g = f - A$

We want to show that $g$ is the constant function, i.e., $g(x) = c$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, let's calculate the differential $dg$ of $g$ at any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$dg(x) = df(x) - dA = df(x) = A$

How do I go from here?

Comment: $x\mapsto f(x)-d_0f(x)$ has zero differential...

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Can you elaborate?

Comment: Elaborate on what?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Are you saying $df = 0$?

Comment: No, I'm saying that $d(f-d_0f)$ is constant $0$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio what do you mean by subtracting the differential of $f$ from $f$ itself, one is a $\mathbb{R}^m$ valued function the other is a linear operator.

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis Indeed, $d_0f$ is a linear operator. Care to remind me its domain and codomain?

Comment: What is $d_0f$? Is it the derivative at a point 0?

Comment: @beginner The differential at $0$, yes.

Comment: The differential at $0$ will still be a linear operator, in order to get the same "type" as $f$ you need evaluation at a point $x$ AND a direction $v$ for $d_x f v$, unless you are in the $n=m=1$ case where you can abuse one by one matrices.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio So you're taking the derivative of a function $f$ - the derivative $C$. So you're subtracting a matrix from a function?

Comment: Can someone explain in depth as an answer, this thread isn't very helpful

Comment: @beginner Ah, ok, so you believe $d_xf$ to be the Jacobi matrix at $x$, rather than the actual differential. Then, in your formalism I mean $d(f-d_0f(\bullet))$ is constant $0$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Can you look at the edit in my post and tell me if it's on the right track and how to complete the proof

Comment: @beginner You went bananas when you started talking about $dx$ rather than calculating the actual differential of $x\mapsto Ax$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio So how should I fix it then

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I fixed up to that step

Comment: The derivative $df$ will be an $m\times n$ matrix. What does it mean for that matrix to be constant?

Comment: @JohnDouma Each entry of the matrix is fixed regardless of the input, is what I have above right?

Answer (score 1):

Your abuse of notation has made you confused. When you define $g=f-A$ in your text you forget to see $A$ as what it is, a function. Therefore $g(x)=f(x)-A(x)$. Another hint is to notice that "$f(x)-A$" makes no sense as $f(x)$ lies in a completely different vector space than the one $A$ belongs to.

From now on your calculations showed that $dg(x)=df(x)-dA(x)=0$. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathrm df = \boldsymbol A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$.

- If $\boldsymbol A = 0$, Let $\boldsymbol a, \boldsymbol b\in \mathbb R^{n}$ and $g : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that $$g(t) = \left\|f((1-t)\boldsymbol a + t\boldsymbol b) - f(\boldsymbol a)\right\|_2^2$$ It is not difficult to prove that $g'(t) = 0$ for every $t\in [0,1]$. Now can you complete the proof?

Comment: Why should $A = 0$? It's a constant, and doesn't have to be zero, right?

Comment: I am assuming $A=0$ the general case is easy if you proved that case.

Comment: Is my approach above in the post incorrect? I'm having trouble following what's going on here and what reduction is happening